# Program that reads X-axis and Y-axis Coordinate Values

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to this and am practicing learning Python and am seeking some advice if possible on a program I'm trying to write.

I'm trying to write a program which will read values inputted from x-axis and y-axis integer coordinate values.

An example would be if the user inputted (1,-1) then 'Yellow Circle' would be displayed in the console.

The problem I'm having is that whatever coordinate values I input 'Yellow Circle' is the only outcome everytime and I can't seem to work out the reason.

Thanks!

```
value = input("Enter coordinates: ")
coordinates = value
if coordinates == {(-5,5), (-4,4), (-3,3), (-2,2), (-1,1)}:
   print("Green Circle")
elif coordinates == {(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5)}:
   print("Blue Circle")
elif coordinates == {(-5,-5), (-4,-4), (-3,-3), (-2,-2), (-1,-1)}:
   print("Red Circle")
else:
   print("Yellow Circle")
```

Comment: Your user input is always of type string but your values are tuples.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand on how to make it so I can still have a user input and the values as tuples?

Comment: One way would be to convert tuples to strings and then replace `==` by `in`. For instance: `if coordinates in {'(-5,5)', "(-4,4)", '(-3,3)', '(-2,2)', '(-1,1)'}:`

Comment: Thanks very much @Bazingaa